# Json Path - Filter on List of List

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
"DATA": [
  {
    "docName": "xyz",
    "result": [
      {
        "attribute": "attr1",
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "attribute": "attr2",
        "value": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "docName": "abc",
    "result": [
      {
        "attribute": "attr1",
        "value": false
      },
      {
        "attribute": "attr2",
        "value": true
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

My use case is to find all the docNames for which the `attr1 = true`

I tried a couple of filter expressions but I am unable to get the doc names. I tried something like this: 
`$.DATA[?(@.result[0].attribute=='attr1' && @.result[0].value == true)].docName` and I get the docNames, but I can't rely on the 1st element of the list. I need to verify if **attr1** is present anywhere in the list with value of **true**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some coding & then figuring out why this is not working, what exactly I found out is that, currently its not possible with jsonpath to get **parent element from filtering child node** (nested json). [Open Issue Link](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287)

Otherwise this might have worked,

`$.DATA[?(@.result[?(@.attribute=="attr1" && @.value==true)])].docName`

Answer (score 2):

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is quite similar to JSONpath so perhaps a jq solution will be of help.  It is, at least, very simple:

```
# find all the docNames for which the attr1 == true
.DATA[]
| select( any(.result[]; .attribute == "attr1" and .value == true) )
| .docName
```

### Java bindings

- https://github.com/eiiches/jackson-jq
- https://github.com/arakelian/java-jq (available from Maven Central)
- Java Native Access wrapper  https://github.com/bskaggs/jjq . Supported platform is Linux only.

Comment: See update, but please note that I have no personal experience with any of these.  Let us know about any pros and cons that you encounter.